# Мерцание при анимации движения дороги

Tags: java

Прграммирую 2д-игру (Назовём ее "Гонки F1").

Суть проблемы: код написан вполне успешно (код заключается в том, что создаётся иллюзия движения машины путем движения дороги за ней), после запуска программы в Eclipse происходит следующее: машина стоит, по нажатию клавиши "вправо", машина набирает скорость, но при этом дорога и сама машина (а также созданные "противники" (Enemy)), мерцают как будто это Новогодняя гирлянда/эпилептический припадок. Я думаю, это какая-то проблема в коде.

```
public class Road extends JPanel implements ActionListener, Runnable 
{
  Timer mainTimer = new Timer(20, this); 
  Image img = new ImageIcon("res/hqdefault.png").getImage(); 
  Player p = new Player(); 
  Thread enemiesFactory = new Thread(this); 
  List<Enemy> enemies = new ArrayList<Enemy>();
  ...
Win7 64-bit Движок: JavaVM
```

Comment: Наверное, стоит добавить к вопросу проблемный код, указать используемый "движок", и вообще с пониманием отнестись к людям с ограниченными ясновидческими возможностями.

Comment: Здесь не помогают по скайпу.

Comment: @zRrr, думаю, на вопрос можно ответить без кода.

Comment: public class Road extends JPanel implements ActionListener, Runnable {
 
 Timer mainTimer = new Timer(20, this);
 
    Image img = new ImageIcon("res/hqdefault.png").getImage();
    
    Player p = new Player();
    
    Thread enemiesFactory = new Thread(this);
    
    List<Enemy> enemies = new ArrayList<Enemy>();

Comment: @NickGromyko - маловато будет :)

Comment: @Igor сейчас загружу картинки пришлю (я прост тут новичок)

Comment: http://rghost.ru/786rgRNZG/image.png       http://rghost.ru/6hRDTpBMC/image.png

Comment: Бог ты мой, awt, eclipse. 2007 =_=. У вас в методе run() вешается основной тред окна на случайное количеств миллисекунд. Потому и дергается. Вынесете обновление в другой поток.

Comment: hqdefault.png - большая картинка для фона? Если нет, попробуйте фон закрашивать в начале `paint`, типа: `g.setColor( getBackground() ); g.fillRect( 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight() );`. Еще укажите операционку, на которой запускаете. Код вроде-бы не должен создавать какие-то артефакты, разве что перемещение будет выглядеть дергано, можно частоту кадров поднять.

Comment: @emre а что именно вписать в метод run()? Или в какой метод, что вписать?

Comment: если вы хотите исправления в коде, пожалуйста скидывайте код. хотя бы сюда http://pastebin.com/